# Swift 2.0 doesn't let me make UIAlertAction

Tags: swift, swift2, xcode7-beta3, uialertaction

this picture should say enough:
[image]

I have been scouring the web to find answers and none else seems to have this problem. I am using Xcode 7 Beta 3 with Swift 2. I can't figure out what's wrong.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

Here's the code:

```
func input(text:String) -> String {
    Say(text)
    let alert:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Goog", message: text, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    [alert .addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({ (textfield: UITextField!) -> Void in
    })]
    var returnValue:String = ""
    let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(
        title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {(action) in
            returnValue = (alert.textFields[0] as UITextField).text!
            return
    }
    return returnValue
}
```

Comment: Show more code and we might be better able to solve your problem. (Where is `returnValue` defined? What is its type?) And post your code as text, not an Xcode screenshot. Not everyone uses SO in a way that lets them easily read text embedded in an image.

Comment: right before I define the action. I simple said: var returnValue:String = ""

Comment: This error tends to be misleading. You should show the 5 lines preceding and following this code snippet (as text please).

Answer (score -1):

You want to use the Swift enum for the action style like this:

```
let alertAction2 = UIAlertAction(title: "My Alert", style: .Default)
        {(action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            // do something with action
            return
        }
```

Or more concisely:

```
let alertAction2 = UIAlertAction(title: "My Alert", style: .Default)
        {action in
            // do something with action
        }
```

Comment: let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(
            title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {(action) in
                returnValue = (alert.textFields[0] as UITextField).text!
                return
        }
        return returnValue

Comment: oh i forgot to tag @PaulRobinson

Comment: You can't return anything from the handler as it returns Void.  All you can do is do something with the action.  Did I understand your comment correctly @NerdyLimeApps ?

Comment: Even after removing the return statement and just assigning the value to the variable it keeps the error still

Comment: @PaulRobinson You do not need the parentheses around `action`, and you do not need a return statement.

Answer (score -1):

```
UIAlertController *altSuccess = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Login Successfully" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction *okSuccess = [UIAlertAction
                                    actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                    style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                    handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                    {
                                        NSLog(@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"email"]);
                                        NSLog(@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"password"]);
                                        [altSuccess dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                    }];

        [altSuccess addAction:okSuccess];

        [self presentViewController:altSuccess animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Its works fine...

Comment: The original question is specifically about using UIAlertAction in Swift. The tags and title of the question even include the word 'Swift'.

Your answer is in Objective-C.